# Null Exception thrown when try to update adapter by means of a context menu

Tags: java, android, android-studio, contextmenu

I'm working on a simple app that store info about a book and it's characters. I am currently working on deleting my book items from a list view by means for a context menu.

The problem is when I press the delete button and try to remove that item from my list view by updating my adapter I get given the `java.lang.NullPointerException` exception. Here is the `onCreateContextMenu` :

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.delete_context_menu,menu);

}
```

Here is the `onContextItemSelected`:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    int index = info.position;
    books.remove(index);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Here is the stack Trace:

> 08-11 09:28:22.061    5542-5542/com.example.opeyemi.storytime
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           Process: com.example.opeyemi.storytime, PID: 5542
>           java.lang.NullPointerException
>                   at com.example.opeyemi.storytime.Activites.MainActivity_StoryBook.onContextItemSelected(MainActivity_StoryBook.java:99)
>                   at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2620)
>                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:353)
>                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:144)
>                   at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:99)
>                   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DialogMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:3864)
>                   at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:741)
>                   at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
>                   at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:884)
>                   at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
>                   at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:167)
>                   at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:941)
>                   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
>                   at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
>                   at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2911)
>                   at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3645)
>                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: post the stacktrace (or logcat), where do you get the NPE?

Comment: [LogCat](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/help/logcat.html)

Comment: Which is line 99? A number of things could be null here.

Comment: (I'm not too sure) check if `item` is null, then check if `item.getMenuInfo()` is null, then check if `info.position` is null, then check if `book.get(index)` is null...

Comment: Only the adapter is null. Line 99 is the line with   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: make sure that you are "calling notifyDataSetChanged() only after initializing the adapter."

Answer (score 1):

You call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` on an adapter which you don't know if it's initialised or not (most probable thing is that it's not).

Be sure that it's well initialised and all will be OK then.

Comment: Thank you . It turns out i was calling an uninitialized adapter

Comment: @opeyemi if it was helpful for solving your issue please mark the answer as the solution for other users with similar problems please.

Comment: I will once i have 15 rep

Comment: @opeyemi I've up voted two interesting posts of you, now you have 16 rep ;)